# Couple of problems with REG ADD command

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-vista, windows-registry

I'm trying to edit Windows Registry through Command Line for some reasons, and I'm having a problem with REG Add Command. 
First of all:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\runas\" /t REG_SZ /v Default /d Take Ownership /f
```

I want to use this command to change value of Default in runas key to Take Ownership. However when I use this command this happens:
[It just adds a key named with a command.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vBr0.jpg)

Another Problem I'm having is with this command:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /t REG_DWORD /v DisableCAD /d 1 /f
```

This one should in theory edit DisableCAD value to 1. However after reboot it doesn't occur, and I have to do this using regedit.
Anyone knows how do I repair it?

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: try removing the last `\ ` from `REG ADD HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\runas\ `

Comment: @mael' Then it says "Incorrect syntax"

Comment: `Take Ownership` has to be double quoted to be seen as a whole, ATM the argument Ownership is unknown.

Comment: Are you aware of the difference `/v Default` (creates a new value named `Default`) and `/ve` (adds an empty value name `(Default)` for the key); in your locale, adds an empty value name `(Domyślna)` for the key?

Comment: @JosefZ That was it! I wasn't aware of the 
difference, now it seems so logical to be honest!

Answer (score 0):

To modify the (default) value use `/ve`. Here is the correct syntax:

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\runas" /t REG_SZ /ve /d "Take Ownership" /f
```